# 16.04: Update to 18.04 fails

Tags: 16.04, upgrade

When I open the updater on my 16.04 system, it tells me that version 18.04 LTS is available; I give it an update, the Release Notes appear, and when I give it an update, it starts downloading until it says "The download is complete", and the tab just disappears, it doesn't update.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have two possibilities:

### Analyze the error and fix it

It depends a bit on how deep you want to dive. This requires reading logs. The logs of a release upgrade should be in `/var/log/dist-upgrade`, if I recall correctly.

### Just set up a new Ubuntu

This saves you from reading logs and gives you 20.04 without upgrading twice.
You would have to backup all your files and reinstall your programs, though.